# glReadPixels fails writing into PBO

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I try to store the rendered image into a PBO with glReadPixels and transfer the pixels into my ByteBuffer object with glMapBuffer afterwards.

But after update() is complete the buffer only contains the dummy data i pass when I call glBufferData(...). So i assume it is glReadPixels that fails to load the data into the PBO. I get the error 1282 (INVALID_OPERATION) after glReadPixels(...), too.

If I try to read the pixels directly into the buffer, it works as expected (although the error still occurs). But for performance reasons I later want to call glMapBuffer(...) first and glReadPixels(...) afterwards, so I can parallize the data processing a bit.

```
public ModelObserver() {
    buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(Display.getWidth() *    Display.getHeight() * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < Display.getWidth() * Display.getHeight(); i++) {
        buffer.put(new byte[] { 0, 127, 0, 0 });
    }
    buffer.flip();

    pixelData = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pixelData);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
}

public void update() {
    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pixelData);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    System.out.println(glGetError());

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pixelData);
    glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE, buffer);


    glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [LWJGL documentation](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glMapBuffer(int,%20int,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer)), your use of `glMapBuffer()` is incorrect. Quoting from the documentation, referring to the 3rd argument:

> Only ByteBuffers returned from this method are to be passed as the old_buffer argument. User-created ByteBuffers cannot be reused.

This means that passing the `buffer` variable as 3rd argument is invalid. The correct usage is:

```
ByteBuffer resBuffer = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE, null);
```

Then you can read the result from `resBuffer`. If you make the same kind of `glMapBuffer()` call again later, you can now pass in this buffer for potential reuse:

```
resBuffer = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE, resBuffer);
```